# Пытаюсь сделать скрипт на pyrogram для вступления в группы(список групп, каждая с новой строки, текстовый документ)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт на pyrogram для вступления в группы(список групп, каждая с новой строки, текстовый документ)
Вот пример ссылок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
api_id = ...
api_hash = "..."
from config import txt
from asyncio import sleep
from pyrogram import Client, filters


app = Client("account", api_id, api_hash)
f = open('text.txt')
with app:
    for line in f.readlines():
            app.join_chat(line.rstrip())
app.run()
```

Пишет следующую ошибку:    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.UsernameInvalid: [400 USERNAME_INVALID]: The username is invalid (caused by "contacts.ResolveUsername")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь передать ссылку на канал, а не его идентификатор.

Иными словами - часть с `https://t.me/` нужно обрезать и передавать сам ID.

Ну и совет на будущее - лучше используйте telethon. На нем в разы легче, да и информации больше

Comment: Мне просто сказали, что пирограм лучше, поэтому вот и сижу на нем. А чем телетон лучше?

Comment: @Wheelz Fun
Телетон лучше годится для работы с чатами. На нем удобно переслать сообщения и целом заниматься граббингом. Пирограм, лично по моему мнению, слегка слабоват. Но документация у него лучше, чем у телетона. В общем - попробуй обе стороны, я чисто посоветовал